# parse_ini_file() does not confirm with manual

Tags: php, ini

I have two questions about some quirks in PHP's [parse_ini_file()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

> There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini
>   files. These include: null, yes, no, true, false, on, off, none.
>   Values null, off, no and false result in "", and values on, yes and
>   true result in "1", unless INI_SCANNER_TYPED mode is used (as of PHP
>   5.6.1).

According to the above, you can use `no` as key if you set `INI_SCANNER_TYPED`. So why does it fail?

```
$ echo "no=1" > a.cfg | php -r 'print_r(parse_ini_file("a.cfg", TRUE, INI_SCANNER_TYPED));'
PHP Warning:  syntax error, unexpected BOOL_FALSE in tmp.cfg on line 1
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.14 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2018 08:41:46) ( NTS )
```

Also, what is the "special meaning" of the characters listed below? The manual does not elaborate.

> Characters ?{}|&~!()^" must not be used in the key and have a special meaning in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpreted the text you quoted. It says:

> **Values** `null`, `off`, `no` and `false` result in `""`, and **values** `on`, `yes` and `true` result in `"1"`, unless `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` mode is used (as of PHP 5.6.1).

It says about the values. In the default mode, these **values** are converted to the strings `""` and `"1"`. In the `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` mode, these **values** are converted to the boolean `false` and `true`.

It doesn't say anything about the keys. These words still cannot be used as keys.

Check how it works: https://3v4l.org/5uZFN

Comment: Honest mistake. The text could really have been more precise. But the more pressing issue, why wouldn't boolean words be allowed in keys? Boolean words are clearly for value use.